# How to use ignore-installed in python setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

For a project of mine, i am using a forked project of pypi. As some people have the depedency already installed, my fork is only installed if the user does not have the dependency already installed.

With pip you can use `--ignore-installed` to ignore the already existing dependency.

How can i achieve the same in my `setup.py`?

I tried

```py
install_requires = ['some_package --ignore-installed']
```

but an error is raised when installing:

```
ERROR: error in dummy setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'--ignore'"
```

Comment: There is no way. Teach your user to run `pip install --ignore-installed`, that's the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there maybe an option to just force-reinstall / ignore-installed one specific install_requirement, e.g. `pip install my_package --force-reinstall name_of_my_fork`

Comment: If you're maintaining the fork, introduce a custom version. E.g. if you forked from `1.2.3`, introduce `1.2.3.post1` and use it to specify the requirement: `install_requires = ['some_package==1.2.3.post1']`.

Comment: As far as i understood from reading https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5898, this will only work until i try to publish the module to pypi. Therefore my question is not-solveable, as pypi will not accept any external links with pip > 18.1. Or do you guys know a way around this?